# Using boxed/atomic values in Scala with Chronicle Map

Tags: java, scala, chronicle, chronicle-map

We're using ChronicleMap to support off-heap persistence in a large number of different stores, but hit a bit a of a problem with the most simple usecase.

First of all, here's the helper I wrote to make creation easier:

```
import java.io.File
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong

import com.madhukaraphatak.sizeof.SizeEstimator
import net.openhft.chronicle.map.{ChronicleMap, ChronicleMapBuilder}

import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object ChronicleHelper {

  def estimateSizes[Key, Value](data: Iterator[(Key, Value)], keyEstimator: AnyRef => Long = defaultEstimator, valueEstimator: AnyRef => Long = defaultEstimator): (Long, Long, Long) = {
    println("Estimating sizes...")

    val entries = new AtomicLong(1)
    val keySum = new AtomicLong(1)
    val valueSum = new AtomicLong(1)
    var i = 0

    val GroupSize = 5000

    data.grouped(GroupSize).foreach { chunk =>

      chunk.par.foreach { case (key, value) =>
        entries.incrementAndGet()
        keySum.addAndGet(keyEstimator(key.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]))
        valueSum.addAndGet(valueEstimator(value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]))
      }

      i += 1

      println("Progress:" + i * GroupSize)
    }

    (entries.get(), keySum.get() / entries.get(), valueSum.get() / entries.get())
  }

  def defaultEstimator(v: AnyRef): Long = SizeEstimator.estimate(v)

  def createMap[Key: ClassTag, Value: ClassTag](data: => Iterator[(Key, Value)], file: File): ChronicleMap[Key, Value] = {
    val keyClass = implicitly[ClassTag[Key]].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[Key]]
    val valueClass = implicitly[ClassTag[Value]].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[Value]]

    val (entries, averageKeySize, averageValueSize) = estimateSizes(data)

    val builder = ChronicleMapBuilder.of(keyClass, valueClass)
      .entries(entries)
      .averageKeySize(averageKeySize)
      .averageValueSize(averageValueSize)
      .asInstanceOf[ChronicleMapBuilder[Key, Value]]

    val cmap = builder.createPersistedTo(file)

    val GroupSize = 5000

    println("Inserting data...")
    var i = 0
    data.grouped(GroupSize).foreach { chunk =>

      chunk.par.foreach { case (key, value) =>
        cmap.put(key, value)
      }

      i += 1

      println("Progress:" + i * GroupSize)
    }

    cmap
  }

  def empty[Key: ClassTag, Value: ClassTag]: ChronicleMap[Key, Value] = {
    val keyClass = implicitly[ClassTag[Key]].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[Key]]
    val valueClass = implicitly[ClassTag[Value]].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[Value]]


    ChronicleMapBuilder.of(keyClass, valueClass).create()
  }


  def loadMap[Key: ClassTag, Value: ClassTag](file: File): ChronicleMap[Key, Value] = {
    val keyClass = implicitly[ClassTag[Key]].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[Key]]
    val valueClass = implicitly[ClassTag[Value]].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[Value]]

    ChronicleMapBuilder.of(keyClass, valueClass).createPersistedTo(file)
  }
}
```

It uses https://github.com/phatak-dev/java-sizeof for object size estimation. Here's the kind of usage we want to support:

```
object TestChronicle {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    def dataIterator: Iterator[(String, Int)] = (1 to 5000).toIterator.zipWithIndex.map(x => x.copy(_1 = x._1.toString))

    ChronicleHelper.createMap[String, Int](dataIterator, new File("/tmp/test.map"))

  }
}
```

But it throws an exception:

> [error] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Key
>   must be a int but was a class java.lang.Integer [error]     at
>   net.openhft.chronicle.hash.impl.VanillaChronicleHash.checkKey(VanillaChronicleHash.java:661)
>   [error]     at
>   net.openhft.chronicle.map.VanillaChronicleMap.queryContext(VanillaChronicleMap.java:281)
>   [error]     at
>   net.openhft.chronicle.map.VanillaChronicleMap.put(VanillaChronicleMap.java:390)
>   [error]     at ...

I can see that it might have something to do with atomicity of Scala's Int as opposed to Java's Integer, but how do I bypass that?

Scala 2.11.7

Chronicle Map 3.8.0

Answer (score 1):

- Seems suspicious that in your test it's `Iterator[(String, Int)]` (rather than `Iterator[(Int, String)]`) for key type is `String` and value type is `Int`, while the error message is compaining about key's type (int/Integer)
- If error message says `Key must be a %type%` it means that you configured that type in the first `ChronicleMapBuilder.of(keyType, valueType)` statement. So in your case it means that you configured `int.class` (the `Class` object, representing the primitive `int` type in Java), that is not allowed, and providing `java.lang.Integer` instance to map's methods (probably you provide primitive `int`s, but they become `Integer` due to boxing), that is allowed. You should ensure that you are providing `java.lang.Integer.class` (or some other Scala's class) to `ChronicleMapBuilder.of(keyType, valueType)` call.
- I don't know what size estimation this project gives: https://github.com/phatak-dev/java-sizeof, but in any case you should specify size in *bytes* that the object will take in *serialized form*. Serialized form itself depends on default serializers, chosen for a specific type in Chronicle Map (and may change between Chronicle Map versions), or custom serializers configured for specific `ChronicleMapBuilder`. So using any information about key/value "sizes" to configure a Chronicle Map, other than out of the Chronicle Map itself, is fragile.  You can use the following procedure to estimate sizes more reliably:

  ```
  public static <V> double averageValueSize(Class<V> valueClass, Iterable<V> values) {
      try (ChronicleMap<Integer, V> testMap = ChronicleMap.of(Integer.class, valueClass)
          // doesn't matter, anyway not a single value will be written to a map
              .averageValueSize(1)
              .entries(1)
              .create()) {
          LongSummaryStatistics statistics = new LongSummaryStatistics();
          for (V value : values) {
              try (MapSegmentContext<Integer, V, ?> c = testMap.segmentContext(0)) {
                  statistics.accept(c.wrapValueAsData(value).size());
              }
          }
          return statistics.getAverage();
      }
  }
  ```

  You can find it in this test: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/7aedfba7a814578a023f7975ef15ba88b4d435db/src/test/java/eg/AverageValueSizeTest.java

  This procedure is hackish, but there are no better options right now.

Another recommendation:

- If your keys or values are kind of primitives (ints, longs, doubles, but boxed), or any other type that  is always of the same size, you shouldn't use `averageKey/averageValue/averageKeySize/averageValueSize` methods, better you use `constantKeySizeBySample/constantValueSizeBySample` method. Specifically for `java.lang.Integer`, `Long` and `Double` even this is not needed, Chronicle Map already knows that those types are constantly sized.